# Cron Job PHP localhost from scratch

Tags: php, cron, backend

My question is if I have a block of code like this

```
$target_date = mktime(0,0,0,7,8,2020); 
$currDate = time();

$diff = $target_date - $currDate; 

$days = floor($diff / 86400); 

$hours = floor($diff / 3600); 

$mins = floor($diff / 60); 

$secs = floor($diff);

if($diff > 0){
//Show countdown page
}else{
// Display landing page
}
```

Does the time get updated every second or so in the time method?
What is a good piece of documentation to implement a cron job?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I would like to make a chron job in localhost from sratch if possible

Comment: HTTP won't allow you to replace the already displayed page, so your question is not really about cron job. It sounds like you ask about the `if` condition with a simple timestamp comparison.

Comment: I want to create a function where I give a date, and before that date the site displays a countdown and after the date it displays a landing page. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: nothing special: `if (time() > strtotime($date)) { ... }`

Comment: You're checking if a date object is greater then a string? I don't think that would work :p Either way it needed to be updated every second or so

Comment: Sounds like a front-end problem, say JavaScript. .... Also, not that it matters at the moment, but your count-down clock calculations are off.